# How to delete GCF function or How to change trigger type of existing one using cloudcustodian?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloudcustodian

I have GCF function deployed using Cloudcustodian c7n-org, I have to change trigger type of existing function with HTTP trigger, when I tried to delete it , it has been deleted, but when I am trying to apply rule, it is created HTTP trigger function rather pub-sub type though my rules file contain pubsub type trigger.

When I create new policy, it is successfully created.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Issue has been fixed. It was due to incorrect cloudcustodian document, I am trying to create rule with pubsub type but triiger_type variable should be like target_type

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer so this post could be seen by the community with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed. It was due to incorrect cloudcustodian document, I am trying to create rule with pubsub type but trigger_type variable should be like target_type.